# Find the derivative of $\int_x^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Hey guys this was given to me as an exercise question and its really confusing. I'm not really sure where to start with this one, and I am assuming that the derivative isn't just $e^{-t^2}  dt$. Anyways, any help is appreciated, thank you!.

Find the derivative of $$\int \limits_x^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt $$

Comment: You want to get rid of that minus sign, right? That aside, do you know Liebniz's rule? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: well ya I know the rule, but I have never really applied it before.  We just learned integration a couple days ago so I'm not really the best at it @EricAuld

Comment: Is the integral written correct? Is it really $- dt$?

Comment: This is quite an advanced example if you just learned integration two days ago. You might want to work up to this one.

Comment: yeah sorry its not, i just edited it @Amzoti

Comment: I am in an honours math class, so we have spent the last 4 lectures on integration and the precise definition. However we have only spent one lecture on the actual computations. He only gave us a few hard examples, he said doing basic integration is easy so we can find examples ourselves @EricAuld

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean find the derivative of $F(x)$, where

$$F(x) = \int_x^{x^2} e^{-t^2} dt.$$

Let $G(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt $. By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

\begin{align*}
F'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}(G(x^2) - G(x)) \\
&= G'(x^2)(2x) - G'(x) \\
&= e^{-x^4}(2x) - e^{-x^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The first exponential should have $x$ in the 4th power.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Absolutely, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just dont understand one part, where does the 2x come from, because when i was thinking of it, i thought the answer should have been e^-(x^4) -  e^-(x^2) @snarski

Comment: The chain rule. If I asked you to differentiate $\sin(x^2)$, you should say the derivative is $\cos(x^2)$ *times the derivative of the inside*, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x^2) = \cos(x^2)*(2x).$ Now instead of $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(x^2)$ consider $G(x)$ and $G(x^2)$.