# Compute a derivative of a function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

If  $h$ is continous, and $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and 
$$F(x)=\int \limits_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$$ then f is differentiable and $F'(x) = h(g(x))g'(x) - h(f(x))f'(x)$

Comment: This is a generalization of your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651170/find-the-derivative-of-int-xx2-e-t2dt). Can you generalize the argument given there?

Comment: By the way, the correct formula should be $F'(x)=h\bigl(g(x)\bigr) g'(x) -h\bigl(f(x)\bigr)f'(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! sorry about that, i just edited it @DavidMitra

Comment: @DavidMitra is this a possible answer; $$F(x)=\int \limits_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$$ 

Let $h(x) =  $$\int \limits_{0}^{x} h(t)dt$

$F'(x) = {d}/{dx} (h(g(x)) - h(f(x)))$

 = $h'(g(x)) - h'(g(x)) $

= $h'(g(x))g'(x) - h'(f(x))f'(x)$

 $F'(x) = h(g(x))g'(x) - h(f(x))f'(x)$

Answer (score 4):

Hint : Just write that $\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t)dt = H(g(x))-H(f(x))$ where $H$ is a primitive of $h$. Then just use the chain rule.

Comment: is this a possible answer; $$F(x)=\int \limits_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$$ 

Let $h(x) =  $$\int \limits_{0}^{x} h(t)dt$

$F'(x) = {d}/{dx} (h(g(x)) - h(f(x)))$

 = $h'(g(x)) - h'(g(x)) $

= $h'(g(x))g'(x) - h'(f(x))f'(x)$

 $F'(x) = h(g(x))g'(x) - h(f(x))f'(x)$

Comment: There a conflict of notation, you name $h$ the antiderivative of $h$ that cancels at the point $0$...